# Distributed Objects and completition block

Tags: macos, cocoa, distributed-objects

I need to call completion block on OSX 10.8 but when I pass completion block to Privileged Helper tool through Distributed Object (NSConnection) and then I call it my Privileged Helper tool crashes.
Does this operation permitted? Or I need to find workaround?
Thank you!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T1w1aMFQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found workaround. I wrapped block into interface and add one method: invoke which calls block. And instance of this class I pass to helper tool through distributed object.